# Generating UML from source and output xml

Tags: xml, uml

Does anybody know a tool to generate an UML diagram from source code and then output XML/XMI ?
My source code contains a lot of classes, so I can't manually drag the classes and generate UML(object aid).
And i am looking for free tool

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MagicDraw (NoMagic Inc), EnterpriseArchitect (SparxSystems)

Answer (score 0):

As always with this type of question, a lot of tools are able to do that e.g. Modelio, MagicDraw, EntrepriseArchitect, RSA, etc. 
So maybe could be more precise when you said generate a UML diagram from source code, do you want to create a Class diagram or something else? If you have a huge piece of code you would not create a unique UML Class diagram with all existing relation between all classes...